# Trying to use a for loop to insert data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am analyzing traffic data, right now each row is data on a accident, there are columns indicating if anyone was seriously injured or died in the accident. I want to create a new column in the data frame called severity and if there is a fatality it should have a value of 2, if someone is seriously injured it should be 1 and it should be 0 if there are no fatalities or injuries. Please help!!

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.denvergov.org/media/gis/DataCatalog/traffic_accidents/csv/traffic_accidents.csv', index_col = 0)
df.head(5)

severity = 0.0
df['Severity'] = severity
i = 1
for df['Severity'] in df.iloc[i]:
    if df['FATALITIES'] == 0.0 and df['SERIOUSLY_INJURED'] == 0.0 :
        df['Severity'] = 0.0
    elif df['FATALITIES'] > 0.0:
        df['Severity'] = 2.0
    elif df['FATALITIES'] == 0.0 and df['SERIOUSLY_INJURED'] > 0.0 :
        df['Severity'] = 1.0
    i = i + 1
```

Getting
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: There are many existing questions that show you how to do this.  Your problem is that you reference an entire *column*, such as df[`FATALITIES`], when you want only the value in the corresponding row.  You didn't bother to tell that fatality reference to grab only the *one* value.  As a result, you tried to compare the *entire column* to `0.0`.  This severely confuses PANDAS.  :-)

Comment: Instead, look at the cited duplicate, and any other references you care to look up.  Take the mindset that "I want PANDAS to give me an entire new column, *all at once*, that is derived from corresponding values in existing columns."  This looks close to what you already have, but gets rid of the iteration loop and any reference to individual rows.